# Extension of PHP `round()` for PHP_ROUND_UP and PHP_ROUND_DOWN - follow-up

Tags: php, performance, floating-point

The original question [can be found here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115444/extension-of-php-round-for-php-round-up-and-php-round-down-performance).

---

While looking at PHP.net this afternoon, I saw [a comment in the documentation for the built-in function `round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#114573). The comment offered two functions for rounding `UP` and `DOWN` (as opposed to just `HALF_UP` and `DOWN`).  I liked the suggestion, but wanted a solution that was one function, instead of 3.

I removed unnecessary call to `preg_replace()` and got clever with `xor` to ensure mimicking `round()` behavior with negative numbers. As for the two `empty()` checks, these ensure less overhead than arithmetic if the provided number is `0`. But I am open to arguments to remove them.

```
define('PHP_ROUND_UP',   11);
define('PHP_ROUND_DOWN', 12);

function fround($number, $precision = 0, $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) {
    if (is_numeric($number) && !empty($number)) {
        switch($mode) {
            case PHP_ROUND_UP:
            case PHP_ROUND_DOWN:
                if (!empty($precision)) {
                    $precision = pow(10, (int) $precision);
                    $number *= $precision;
                }
                if ($mode == PHP_ROUND_UP xor ($number < 0)) {
                    $number = ceil($number);
                } else {
                    $number = floor($number);
                }
                if (!empty($precision) && !empty($number)) {
                    $number /= $precision;
                }
                break;
            default:
                $number = round($number, $precision, $mode);
                break;
        }
    }
    return (float) $number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is good that you were able to remove the call to `preg_replace()`. It is not necessarily bad to have such calls but they can be expensive in terms of replacing characters in strings - at least compared to simpler replace functions.

You stated in [a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115444/extension-of-php-round-for-php-round-up-and-php-round-down#comment214372_115449):

> Updated, the use of `xor` is much more performant, and I LOVE getting a chance to use it when I can

There is a `switch` statement with two blocks - the first for the two cases where `$mode` matches the new constants, and the second for the `default` cases. It would be a lot simpler to just use `if` and `else` statements - one could likely utilize `xor` in the condition!

While the code may have been run on PHP 5.5 or earlier, [PHP 5.6 introduced the exponentiation operator (`**`)](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.0) so that could be used instead of calling `pow()`.  In [this review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87600/120114) Kiko mentions how "*The `pow()` function and `/` operator are computationally somewhat expensive.*" and offers alternatives. While it may not be much faster to use the operator it would require fewer function calls.

Also [in that previously mentioned review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87600/120114) the first code sample uses a variable named `$factor` to hold the multiplication factor to handle the precision. In the code above `$precision` gets overwritten. While it is apparent that the original value of `$precision` is not needed after `pow()` is called it would be cleaner to not overwrite that variable - and use a more appropriate name like `$factor`.

If the version of PHP that the code runs on has been updated past 7 (and hopefully that is true given [supported versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)) then [Scalar type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.scalar-type-declarations) can be added for the arguments. That could allow for elimination of some of the calls to functions like `is_numeric()`.